# What is the best way to maintain a subtree branch?

Tags: git, repository, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a git repo and would like to create branch that only contains the contents of a sub-directory of Master.

Here's a visual representation of what I want:

```
Master Branch
 |__app
 | |__scripts
 | | |__partials
 | | | |__partial_1.js
 | | | |__partial_2.js
 | | |__main.js
 | |__styles
 | | |__partials
 | | | |__base.scss
 | | | |__typography.scss
 | | |__main.scss
 | | |__main.css
 | |__index.html
 |__dist
 | |__scripts
 | | |__main.js
 | |__styles
 | | |__main.css
 | |__index.html
 |__.gitignore
 |__gulpfile.js

Deploy Branch
 |__scripts
 | |__main.js
 |__styles
 | |__main.css
 |__index.html
```

The purpose of this deploy branch is to maintain a version of the project that can be deployed from easily. That way I don't have to pull from a subdirectory of Master.

I was able to achieve the start of this with `git subtree split --prefix=dist -b Deploy` but I'm not sure if this was the right way to go about this, and if it was I have no idea how to now merge new changes to `master/dist/` to `deploy/`.

The only info I could find about merging a subtree was about merging it back to master, not merging master changes to the subtree branch.

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks

---

### Workaround

My current workaround is to `git branch -D Deploy` and then `git subtree split -P dist -b Deploy` for each deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I guess I can just run `git subtree split -P dist -b deploy` regardless of whether or not deploy already exists. Seems to work to me. Any reason not to do this?